# How to extend union type in extending interface

Tags: typescript, union-types

My situation

```
interface ElectionRaw {
  status: 'before' | 'in_progress' | 'counting_in_progress' | 'done',
}

interface Election extends ElectionRaw {
  transformed: true,
  status: 'long_before' | ElectionRaw['status'],
}
```

throws:

```
Interface 'Election' incorrectly extends interface 'ElectionRaw'.
  Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
    Type '"before" | "in_progress" | "counting_in_progress" | "done" | "long_before"' is not assignable to type '"before" | "in_progress" | "counting_in_progress" | "done"'.
      Type '"long_before"' is not assignable to type '"before" | "in_progress" | "counting_in_progress" | "done"'.(2430)
```

[link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIBsILMA9iAJTgHdkBvAKGWQGcw4wBXGgLmQHIAjCGXKCdsgA%20HUAH0ADlFwBzfjRqCR7BLkbhQMseKmz5i4RwAm%20AQBoKAXwoVQkWIhQYsOfMggAPSCCM00mbDxCEnIqZDAoOBAaXigAWwgjNgjGCAtqOgZmNnZ0fC1uWIFDZ0D8ImIAbXZMpkUAXQtLIA)

Many thanks for advices

Comment: Is `ElectionRaw`  your custom type or it is from third party library ?

Comment: The errors is throwing because you are extending `ElectionRaw` which expect to have a `status` property with the exact values, instead and in your `Election` interface you added a `status` property which has an unexpected new value (`long_before`) so that in this case both `status` properties will not be compatible, in that case you can fix that by adding to `interface ElectionRow` status property this value in the last of your line after `| 'done'` this : `| string` so it will be : `status: ...|....| 'done' | string`

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez adding string at the end will allow any value, I want to keep exact values.. ElectionRaw is type in form it comes from API, Election is type after some transformations, like adding default values.. which in this case if status comes as null I transfrom it to `long_before`, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Working with `type` instead of `interface`, you could achieve it like:

```js
type ElectionRaw  = {
  status: 'before' | 'in_progress' | 'counting_in_progress' | 'done',
}

type Election = {
    [key in keyof ElectionRaw]: key extends 'status' ? (ElectionRaw[key] | 'long_before') : ElectionRaw[key]
} & {
    transformed: true
}

const election: Election = {
    status: 'long_before',
    transformed: true
}
```

or by using `Omit` you can do it as follow:

```js
type ElectionRaw  = {
  status: 'before' | 'in_progress' | 'counting_in_progress' | 'done',
}

type Election = Omit<ElectionRaw, "status"> & {
    status: ElectionRaw['status'] | 'long_before'
    transformed: true
}

const election: Election = {
    status: 'long_before',
    transformed: true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how correct this is, but you could omit the `status`.

```ts
interface ElectionRaw {
  status: 'before' | 'in_progress' | 'counting_in_progress' | 'done',
}

interface Election extends Omit<ElectionRaw, 'status'> {
  transformed: true,
  status: 'long_before' | ElectionRaw['status'],
}
```

Or use generics.

```ts
interface ElectionRaw<STATUS = 'before' | 'in_progress' | 'counting_in_progress' | 'done'> {
  status: STATUS,
}

interface Election extends ElectionRaw<'long_before' | ElectionRaw['status']> {
  transformed: true,
}
```